# How to parse newLine characters in JSON string

Tags: iphone, json, parsing, ios4, ios-simulator

I am trying to parse this string .... but due to **"message_of_the_day" key** , JSON is not able to recognize the string as it contains newLine characters (\n).How would I parse this JSON string, rest of all JSON webservices works fine for me.

**Json Response :**

```
{"tblMessageOfTheDay":[{"customer_id":"1659","application_id":"1001","message_of_the_day":"Set your Message



GDSFSFDS
SF
ADS
DSFS
F"}]}
```

**Code :**

I gave lot of try to solve out this issue.....but still having the same problem.

```
-(void)DataCollectedSuccessfully:(NSString *)responseString
{

     NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue]; // Main code .. with didn;t work
    id result = [responseString JSONValue]; // I tried for it, it that object won;t get recognized, but this trick didn't work.
    NSLog(@"%@",result);

    NSDictionary *results = [[responseString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] JSONValue]; // Even tried to remove the newLine characters & extra space.

 }
```

**Error :**

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=5 \"Unescaped control character '0xa'\" UserInfo=0x6235db0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unescaped control character '0xa'}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: message_of_the_day\" UserInfo=0x6224a50 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6235e00 \"Unescaped control character '0xa'\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: message_of_the_day}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Expected value while parsing array\" UserInfo=0x6224a80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6235d20 \"Object value expected for key: message_of_the_day\", NSLocalizedDescription=Expected value while parsing array}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: tblMessageOfTheDay\" UserInfo=0x6224af0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6224ab0 \"Expected value while parsing array\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: tblMessageOfTheDay}"
)
```

Comment: In valid JSON, control characters (U+0000 through U+001F, which includes \n = U+000A) **must** be escaped. Your JSON string is not valid JSON, which is why the JSON parser is complaining about it. When in doubt, http://jsonlint.com is an excellent service to validate JSON strings.

Comment: @Bavarious I have already checked out this string on JSON Parser... If I remove the extra spaces betweem message then it showed me the Valid JSON .But I need to stick on the same format... :(

Comment: You might be able to find a more forgiving parser but the two parsers I know, SBJSON and JSONKit, will refuse to parse invalid JSON.

Comment: @Bavarious Not an issue I have done it with the same parser using some tricks.BTW thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just a simple way which worked for me.
The problem was with the posting the data from iPhone, if I use to enter some new line character, it creates the problem & more on, the same data was required to be shown on website too ,thats tried to replace the \n with 
 tag as , it can be easily parsed at website too.

**Here is the code snippet :**

```
[[messageView text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" br "];
```

I need to use br since the same web service data need to be used in website too.

I am not sure about the way of doing this, but yes It solved my problem at both ends i.e Website as well as in iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace "\n" with some other characters while parsing and again replace those characters with "\n" before assigning this value to some control.

Comment: Blindly replacing `\n` with something else will break the JSON string if it contains `\n` outside of strings.

Comment: @Nishant can you help me with some code snippet, it's really a tuff time for me...

Comment: @Bavarious you are right ... that won;t make any sense.Even if I remove the /n ...it shows me the error. I think the issue is with the UTF format the data returned from server.

Comment: Just solve this with with below code : [[messageView text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" br "];.I need to use br since the same web service data need to be used in website too.

Answer (score 1):

Only @"\n" replaceby @"" will not work in objective-c and not @"\b",
I was having same issue.

```
NSString *jsonstring = [jsonStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];
jsonstring = [jsonstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
```

this will delete all carriage return and newline created by html page.

I solved issue by this. :)